# jQuery Tmpl Value with Property not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using this -> https://github.com/jquery/jquery-tmpl

What I need is to display an array of objects using the said plugin recursively.

How come this doesn't work? -> `{{if value.exists != false}} checked {{/if}}`

Please consider this code:

```
{{each list}}
    <li><label class="checkbox{{if value.exists != false}} active{{/if}}"><input type="checkbox" {{if value.exists != false}} checked{{/if}} disabled>${$value.type}</label></li>
{{/each}}
```

The object:

```
{ "list": 
    [
        { type: "GRAPH_A", exists: true },
        { type: "GRAPH_B", exists: false },
        { type: "GRAPH_C", exists: false },
    ]
}
```

Here's the error I get:

> ReferenceError: value is not defined Source File:
>   app/scripts/jquery.tmpl.min.js
>
> Line: 10

Comment: what is the list contains of

Comment: where is the `value` object

Comment: @Arun There you go. Made an edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
{{each list}}
    <li><label class="checkbox{{if exists != false}} active{{/if}}"><input type="checkbox" {{if exists != false}} checked{{/if}} disabled>${type}</label></li>
{{/each}}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/t33Kz/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this demo ... see the source code might it be usefull.
[Using {{if}} and {{else}}](http://jquery.github.com/jquery-tmpl/demos/step-by-step/0_tmpl-read-only/3_if-else-tag.html)

data:

```
var movies = [{
        Title: "Meet Joe Black",
        Languages: "English and French",
        Subtitles: "English"
    }, {
        Title: "Eyes Wide Shut",
        Subtitles: "French and Spanish"
    }, {
        Title: "The Mighty"
    }
];
```

html:

```
<script id="movieTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    <tr>
        <td>${Title}</td>
        <td>
            {{if Languages}}
                Alternative languages: <em>${Languages}</em>.
            {{else Subtitles}}
                Original language only... <br/>Subtitles in <em>${Subtitles}</em>.
            {{else}}
                Original version only, without subtitles.
            {{/if}}
        </td>
    </tr>
</script>
```

Comment: Lone link is considered a poor answer (see [faq#deletion]) since it is meaningless by itself and **target resource is not guaranteed to be alive in the future**. [It would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference (like I did).